Did the Jews do anything to merit the end of the Persian exile?
Whereas during the slavery in Egyptian the Torah indicates that the Jews cried out and their cries reached Hashem, I am not aware of any similar verse which indicates the Jews did any action which led to the end of their exile under Darius. I realize that the exile had to come to an end at some point because it was prophesized to last for 70 years, however I would like to know if the sages propose any action on the part of the people which triggered the end of their exile at that time.

Accepted the Torah in gemara Shabbos voluntarily.

Keep in mind that the rebuilding of the Beis Hamikdash under Darius' reign was by no means the end of the Persian exile. A few years later, in fact, the Leviim's long prayer (Nechemiah 9) ends with a bitter cry that "behold, today we are slaves" to the Persian autocrats even while living in our own land. The actual Persian exile ended with Alexander's conquests, meaning that the Jews went straight from one exile to the next.

@YDJ that didn't trigger the redemption

@Meir so Jeremiah's prophecy didn't come to pass?

@rikitikitembo Of course it did. 70 years after Babylonia came to power, its empire was overthrown; 70 years after Nebuchadnezzar first made Judea his vassal, Cyrus gave permission to the Jews to return to the Land of Israel and start rebuilding the Beis Hamikdash; and 70 years after its destruction, Darius gave permission to restart the rebuilding.

R. Michoel Miller, a scholar of Maharal, wrote a small book "Darkness and Destiny: The Four Empires in Midrash and Beyond" which collects all midrashic and outside sources on the four kingdoms. Unfortunately, it does not have a commentary, but it did pointed out for me the Midrash Bereshis Rabba 99:2 which gives cryptic reasons for the fall of each of the four empires.
Here's the part relevant to the question asked:

Benjamin opposite the kingdom of Media – this one was likened to a wolf, and that one was likened to a wolf. This one was likened to a wolf: “Benjamin is a wolf that mauls” (Genesis 49:27); and that one was likened to a wolf: “Behold another, a second beast, resembling a bear [ledov]” (Daniel 7:5) – Rabbi Ḥanina said: Ledov is written, but it was called dev. (Commentary: *The word dov, bear, is sometimes written with a vav. In this instance it is written without a vav, such that it can be read dev, which is Aramaic for ze’ev, wolf. Thus, the midrash is saying that Media is compared to a wolf.)  This is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yoḥanan, as Rabbi Yoḥanan said: ... “a wolf of the deserts will plunder them” (Jeremiah 5:6) – this is Media. Into the hands of whom did the kingdom of Media fall? Into the hands of Mordekhai, who descended from Benjamin.

The midrash is amaizingly cryptic, so what does it mean? First of all, according to wikipedia, wolves live in packs which are led by strong leaders. Therefore, the midrash notes that in Persia there was a problem of the community leadership and internal community strife.
We know, that Persian empire offered people unbelievable freedom, so that any girl could become a queen. Yalkut Meam Loez 1:5 in the name of Yearos D'vash points that the seven day banquet in Shushan began during the 10 days of repentance on the 3rd of Tishrei and ended on Yom Kippur (with kosher food). That was why Mordekhai protested that people should not come to the banquet, but they did not listen.
Rabbeinu Bachya ibn Pekudah in his commentary on Shemos 38:25 points another problem among the Jews: they no longer viewed each other as equal members one community. Why did Haman offer 10,000 kikar of silver to Achashveirosh to eliminate all the jews, which weighted against the 100 kikar of shekalim brought by 600,000 Jews? Haman used the bigest valuation of Arachin, 50 shekels (Vayikra 27:3) per male. Compared to half-shekel, 50 shekalim gives a factor of 100 and 10,000 = 100*100. In other words, Haman's accusation against the Jews was that even when raising money we did it according to the laws of Arachin (individually) and not according to the laws of Shekalim (same value for everyone).
Certainly, the point of Rabbeinu Bachya also goes against the rule that in a pack of wolves everyone but the leader is equal. Today we fix these problems with the mitzvah of shekalim before Purim and sending the same mishloach manos, and of course with recognising the true value of Torah leaders like Mordekhai. Additional important point is made in gemara Shabbos 88a:

Rava said: Even so, they again accepted it willingly in the time of Ahasuerus, as it is written: “The Jews ordained, and took upon them, and upon their seed, and upon all such as joined themselves unto them” (Esther 9:27), and he taught: The Jews ordained what they had already taken upon themselves through coercion at Sinai.

Finally, the above midrash Bereshis Rabba 99:2 fits well with historical calculations in the book by R. Alexander Hool "The Challenge of Jewish History", which shows that Achashverosh was Cambyses and the son of Esther Darius the 1st had lost the war to Alexander the Great (contrary to the academic historical dogma from Herodotus that it was Darius the 3rd). See also, Carl Olof Jonsson "The Gentile Times Reconsidered".
